# Equal pointers are different?

Tags: pointers, go

This code creates two interface variables from the same pointer. The prints demonstrate that they are the same pointer (as opposed to storing copies of `s` and `s2`). Yet, the last print says `i1` is not the same as `i2`. Why?

```
package main
import "fmt"
func main() {
    var s T = &struct{string}{}
    var s2 *struct{string} = s
    var i1 interface{} = s
    var i2 interface{} = s2
    fmt.Println(s)
    s.string = "s is i1"
    fmt.Println(i1)
    s.string = "s is i2"
    fmt.Println(i2)
    fmt.Println(i1==i2)
}

type T *struct{string}
```

```
$ go run a.go
&{}
&{s is i1}
&{s is i2}
false
```

Comment: Think the interface{}s themselves may contain pointers to different pointers to strings; Google up RSC's godata post. If your goal is (were?) to learn about corner cases in Go, there're a lot of readable docs (spec, etc.) that document them. No rule against just having fun with SO, but if I'm going to waste my time I'd rather waste my time helping people do productive work. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what the Go langauge specification [says about comparing interface values](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Comparison_operators):

> Two interface values are equal if they have identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values or if both have value nil.

The value in `i1` has the named type `T`.  The value in `i2` has the anonymous type `*struct{string}`. Because the two values have different dynamic types, the interface values are not equal.

To see the types, add this line to your program:

```
fmt.Printf("i1: %T, i2: %T\n", i1, i2)
```

This line will print:

```
i1: main.T, i2: *struct { string }
```

Comment: "Interface values are comparable. Two interface values are equal if [...] or if both have value nil." If this is true, then why does `var i1 interface{} = nil; var i2 interface{} = (*int)(nil); fmt.Println(i1==i2)` print false?

Comment: Do clauses from the FAQ override the spec in Go?

Comment: So then, the value `(*int)(nil)` isn't actually nil?

Comment: As you carefully [...]'d out of the quote above above, the dynamic type of the interface value takes part in comparing interface values. If you believe the spec should be clearer that "value nil" refers only to having both a nil value and a nil dynamic type, open an issue and congratulate yourself.

Comment: I see. It must mean the "identical dynamic types and (equal dynamic values or if both have value nil)" (isn't that equivalent to "identical dynamic types and values"?) as opposed to "(identical dynamic types and equal dynamic values) or (if both have value nil)". The "or if" made me think it's the latter.

Comment: Possible it was phrased that way because the author thought alternative phrasings would suggest `nil` itself was a dynamic type, and the spec author didn't want to suggest that, and the FAQ refers to a `(nil,nil)` interface value because they're explicitly being informal there (lead para says "schematically"). Possible (indeed, not mutually exclusive with the other possibilities) that spec phrasing's just odd and they didn't think of this reading. Seriously, you should feel free to open an issue on Go if you want; though it feels academic to me, specs do try really hard for clarity/precision.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to the checking an `error` value against `nil` which is covered [in this FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error), basically for the equality to pass they must be of the same value and type but `i1` is of type `T` and `i2` is of type `*struct{string}`.